# Dismiss or hide listview item with swipe

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to implement this functionality which would be similar to dismissing phone notifications. Any suggestion in another direction or example would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a CardView perhaps? https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this implementation (if that what you want):

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to try it but this library looks promising: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Also this one:
https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo